# How to create and use a custom OpenAI gym environment on google colab?

Tags: python, package, google-colaboratory, openai-gym

I have succeeded in creating a custom OpenAI gym environment on my computer following this tutorial: https://web.archive.org/web/20181128171840/https://medium.com/@apoddar573/making-your-own-custom-environment-in-gym-c3b65ff8cdaa

Then I've uploaded my package to colab as a zip file and installed it:

```
!unzip /content/gym-foo.zip
!pip install -e /content/gym-foo
```

After that I've tried using my custom environment:

```
import gym
import gym_foo
gym.make("gym_foo-v0")
```

This actually works on my computer, but on google colab it gives me:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gym_foo'
```

Whats going on? How can I use my custom environment on google colab?

Comment: For anyone thinking of opening a ticket with google colab, look at this [issue](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/147)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need to restart your runtime. It should work after that. I usually have the following at the top of my notebook. I run the following, whenever I made a change in my environment code to update the version on colab.

```
%%capture
!rm -r Foo_env
!git clone https://github.com/username/Foo_env.git
!pip install -e Foo_env
```

I then restart my runtime through running the following block.

```
import os

def restart_runtime():
  os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)

restart_runtime()
```

You'll get a warning that the environment quite unexpectedly, or something similar, but that's fine. Now the notebook has the newest version of my repo downloaded and installed. Using a simple `import gym_foo` should work now.

Comment: Back when I tried, it did not work. Now however it does. Maybe I did something stupid. Thank you.

Comment: I updated my answer to give more details and respond to the answer/question below.

Comment: Oh great, thanks for the `os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)`! For anyone who doesn't know: `os.kill` sends a signal (here 9 - SIGKILL - kills the process) to the process given in the first argument (here `os.getpid()` the calling process, the notebook I guess)